# How to transcode 50 H264 Streams with FFMPEG more efficient?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, x264

i need to (Re-)Transcode ~ 50 Live-Streams. These streams are in H264 with 720p to 1080p and bitrates up to 10M. I just want to reduce the quality and bitrate of the streams to up to 720p with max. 2M Bitrate.

That's what i'm doing right now:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "http://domain.tld/path/file.ext" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -vf scale=-2:720 -b:v 2M -maxrate 2M -bufsize 1M -acodec libfdk_aac -f flv "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/stream_xyz"
```

My Server CPU (2 x Xeon E5-2630 v3) is already at 100% with just 12 streams. I will upgrade my server to 2 x Xeon Gold 5118 next month, but i don't think, that this will give me that much more power.

Can someone help me, to do this more efficient?

Would it be more efficient / cheaper to do this with GPUs?

Or any other ideas, to do that as efficient and cheap as possible?

Thanks

Comment: Hardware accelerated encoding will generally sacrifice speed for quality, so at the same bitrate it won't look as good as an output from x264. Maybe not a concern. Additionally, there may be artificial limits on the number of streams that can be simultaneously encoded on consumer level hardware, but I've seen discussions (can't remember where) detailing ways around that.

Comment: I don't know any open source or free solution for your use case. But what you are looking for is called 'transrating'. Over simplified - you'd reuse the existing stream and round some more. You'll find research papers like: https://malah.net.technion.ac.il/files/2017/08/Naama-H264_Video-Technology-09-1.pdf and may be some commercial products.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone help me, to do this more efficient?

Nope. Video encoding takes a lot of CPU. period. If there was a "more efficient" way it would already be default.

You can go "cheaper" by using hardware acceleration (nvenc, quicksync, etc but you won't get 12 streams out of that, and the quality will be worse). Or use a slower x264 preset (ultrafast) and sacrifice quality for speed that way.

Only other option is to trade capex for opex use a cloud based service.